# Firebase disable functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

On a Vue app I enabled firebase functions to send messages from contact form.

I do not want to use functions anymore, but only hosting and firestore.

I have removed the function  from index.js in functions folder, but when I do `firebase deploy` I get:

> Error: Your project must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go)
> plan to complete this command. Required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com
> can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete.

This happened after upgrading to node 10, and it's the reason I don't want to use functions anymore.

How do I remove functions completely from project?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to deploy after upgrading by removing:

```
"functions": {
  "source": "functions"
}
```

in firebase.json. Optionally I also removed functions folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete all the functions manually in the Firebase console.

Or, you can downgrade back to node 8 and redeploy an empty index.js to delete the functions.  You will need to use a version of the CLI [less than version 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316988/firebase-cli-deploy-error-deploys-to-runtimes-below-node-js-10-are-now-disable).

Comment: I was able to deploy after downgrading node and CLI. But sorry am I not supposed to upggrade CLI anymore after that? If I do then I need to upgrade to node 10. And then I keep getting same warning..

Comment: Even if index.js is empty, deploy (after downgrade) was successful and there are no functions listed on console

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're done.  If there are no functions listed in the console, then nothing to should execute.  You can upgrade the CLI again and use other Firebase products.